# v-if doesn't update correctly when watcher sets enum data variable

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a problem with `v-if` in combination with watchers and data in vue. I have the following SFC:

```
<script lang="ts">
// imports ...

export default defineComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            store,
            api: new Api(Constants.baseUrl),
            game: null as (Game | null),
            playerIcons: Constants.playerIcons,
            gameId: this.$route.params.id as string,
            poller: null as number | null,
            whoseTurn: null as Color | null,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        async pollGame(): Promise<void> {
            try {
                this.game = await this.api.readGame(this.gameId);
                // snip
            } catch (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        },
        colorToNotation(color: Color): string | null {
            if (color === Color.A) {
                return "A";
            } else if (color === Color.B) {
                return "B";
            } else if (color === Color.C) {
                return "C";
            } else if (color === Color.D) {
                return "D";
            }

            return null;
        },
        notationToColor(notation: string): Color | null {
            if (notation === 'a') {
                return Color.A;
            } else if (notation === 'b') {
                return Color.B;
            } else if (notation === 'c') {
                return Color.C;
            } else if (notation === 'd') {
                return Color.D;
            }

            return null;
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
        this.pollGame();
        this.poller = setInterval(this.pollGame, Constants.pollingInterval);
    },
    unmounted() {
        if (this.poller) {
            clearInterval(this.poller!);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        'game.notation'(newValue) {
            // snip

            const playerNotation: string = newValue[newValue.length - 1];
            let previousTurn: Color | null = this.whoseTurn;
            this.whoseTurn = this.notationToColor(playerNotation);
            console.log(`Set turn from ${this.colorToNotation(previousTurn!)} to ${this.colorToNotation(this.whoseTurn!)}`);
        }
    }

    // snip
});
</script>

<template>
    <!-- snip -->
    <div v-if="game">
        <div id="whose-turn" v-if="whoseTurn">
            Turn:
            <img class="player-icon" :src="playerIcons.get(whoseTurn)" />
            {{ game.getPlayer(whoseTurn)!.name }}
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            No turn
        </div>

        <!-- snip -->
    </div>
    <!-- snip -->
</template>
```

The game engine gives back a notation in which the last letter indiciates whose turn it is: '`a`', '`b`', '`c`'  or '`d`' (in this order). Unfortunately, whenever player a is at turn, the `v-if` goes to false and "`No turn`" is displayed. However, the logs indicate that when the game is read from the server, it is set to '`A`' and is never null again:

Console log:

```
Set turn from null to A
Set turn from A to B
Set turn from B to C
Set turn from C to D
Set turn from D to A
Set turn from A to B
Set turn from B to C
Set turn from C to D
Set turn from D to A
Set turn from A to B
Set turn from B to C
Set turn from C to D
Set turn from D to A
...
```

While I see in the browser (listed here all at once instead of one at a time in the browser):

```
No turn
Turn: B
Turn: C
Turn: D
No turn
Turn: B
Turn: C
Turn: D
No turn
Turn: B
Turn: C
Turn: D
...
```

The logs show that variable `this.whoseTurn` has the correct value; but infortunately the `v-if` seems to remember that `this.whoseTurn` is `null` from the first milliseconds when waiting on the game data from the server, and keeps associating turn A with `null`?

This is really confusing, what is going on?

Comment: How is `Color` defined?  Could be that `Color.A` == `null`. In that case `colorToNotation()` would still return "A" for your log statements but result false for `v-if="whoseturn"`

Comment: Color is just an enum: `export enum Color {A,B,C,D}`. If I add `console.log(playerNotation, this.whoseTurn);` before `console.log(\`Set turn from ${this.colorToNotation(previousTurn!)} to ${this.colorToNotation(this.whoseTurn!)}\`);` I get the following: `a 0 b 1 c 2 d 3 a 0 b 1 c 2 d 3 a 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By answering the comment of @yoduh I've fumbled on the solution. The enum does not have values assigned:

```
export enum Color {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
}
```

So the default value for `Color.A` is `0` which the `v-if` statement evaluates as false. This is why everytime player A plays, it's turn is displayed as "`No turn`".

I've fixed it like this:

```
export enum Color {
    A = 1,
    B,
    C,
    D,
}
```